# Check whether returned file is XML or not

Tags: php, xml, curl

I need to check the return value of a website output. In case of valid login details it returns a XML file and in case of invalid login details it just returns a string saying "You entered a invalid id".

My problem is I have used this code to check,

```
$ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $output = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            if(simplexml_load_string($output)){
                echo 'Is XML';
             }else{
               echo 'Not XML';
                 }
```

The problem is it is checking and displaying the message, but I am getting these errors

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^
>   in

Is there a way to sort out these errors. I have been searching in the internet for the past hour without any success.

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Check if the first 5 characters equal `<?xml`, that should be a pretty good clue.

```
if(substr($output, 0, 5) == "<?xml") {
    echo 'Is XML';
} else {
    echo 'Not XML';
}
```

Comment: I think this one would be better `strpos($output, '<?xml') === 0`

Comment: @Yekver technically substr would be faster, since it doesn't have to search the whole string. The difference is probably negligible though.

Comment: Simple and quite elegant when you receive files that are in fact xml even whitout an .xml extension ...

Comment: A little late, but: This solution will not treat valid XML 1.0 files without the XML declaration as what they are. The XML declaration is recommended but not mandatory. See the first paragraph of that answer over there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7007781/1704604

Comment: In particular this won't work with XMP files, which are XML files beginning with `<?xpacket` so I assume there must be a bunch of other XML types that begin with their own stuff too.

Answer (score 9):

```
$result = simplexml_load_string ($data, 'SimpleXmlElement', LIBXML_NOERROR+LIBXML_ERR_FATAL+LIBXML_ERR_NONE);
if (false == $result) echo 'error';
```

Comment: But if `if (false == $result)` is really false, I'm getting an error `Node no longer exists`. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Could also be because the first line of the return data is blank - try `$output = trim($output)` before you parse the string as XML.