# How to check if it is a xml file or a json file in PHP

Tags: php, json, xml

How i can check in php if the url contains xml of json file.
so in the $url holds the url and than it should check whethere it is a xml file or a json file.

```
$url = 'http://hello.asdasd/asdasd/asdasd';

if (($url == JSON) = TRUE){ // how to  check it is a json file, do the follwing action

    $xml = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($xml, true);
} 
else if ($url == XML) = TRUE){ // how to check it is a XML file, do the follwing action
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
}
```

Any advice will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple process:

- [Attempt to *decode* it as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php)
- Check for errors
- [Attempt to *load* it as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211645/check-whether-returned-file-is-xml-or-not)
- Check for errors

You have most of this code already, just adjust your `if` statements to check the results of attempting to *decode/load* the data.

Also since it's a web resource, you could cross-check the mime type. This would require using something other than `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the solution for [checking a file is valid Json.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php)

Then you simply check if the string is JSON then assume XML - if it's guaranteed to be one or the other!

Comment: You may not want to *assume* it's XML just because it's not JSON.

Comment: That's why I said "if it's guaranteed to be one or the other"