# How to do XML Parsing

Tags: xml, qtp

This is my sample XML File:

```
<Cars>
     <Make name="Maruthi">
         <Model>
             <Name>Wagnor</Name>
             <Release>2000</Release>
         </Model>
     </Make>
     <Make name="Maruthi">
         <Model>
              <Name>Swift</Name>
              <Release>2005</Release>
         </Model>
     </Make>
     <Make name="Hundai">
         <Model>
             <Name>i10</Name>
             <Release>2003</Release>
         </Model>
     </Make>
</Cars>
```

I want to retrieve all cars where Make Name is=Maruthi(so here i am expecting two Cars out of three)

```
Set o_XML=XMLUtil.CreateXMLFromFile("E:\Programming Samples\QTP Samples\Cars.xml")
set o_ChildPath=o_XML.ChildElementsByPath("/Cars/Make/[name='Maruthi']")
```

'Here XMLUtil is utility object provided by QTP, but i dont see any problem there.

The only problem is in evaluating the expression. I tried different expressions but i am getting "expression must evalute to a node-set".

Can someone help in here?

Comment: It's hard to know how to help you when we don't even know what language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use JAXB parser. It would get a list of car objects for you and then you can retrieve all car of "Maruthi" make.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you're trying to pass an XPath expression to `ChildElementsByPath`.  If it accepts XPath (sorry, I don't use the tool and can't find documentation on the Web), you want the expression to be `/Cars/Make[name='Maruthi']` (drop the last slash).  If it doesn't accept XPath, you may want to use `/Cars/Make` and use your own code to filter out the unwanted makes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need an XML header?
You can read here about this:

[Is a valid XML file required xml header declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007427/is-a-valid-xml-file-required-xml-header-declaration-xml-version-1-0-encodin)