# Read Cyrillic Characters

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file.

This file has attributes and the values are in Cyrillic.

How I can read this xml file?

Ex Xml:

```
<Ships>
    <Ship X="3" Y="Г" Length="3" Orientation="vertical" />
    <Ship X="7" Y="А" Length="2" Orientation="horizontal" />
    <Ship X="10" Y="Ж" Length="1" />
</Ships>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow: what have you tried?

Comment: Use the XMLReader: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp

Comment: What's wrong with `[XmlDocument.Load]`(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx)?

Comment: I would look into XML serialization. As for the characters you're trying to support... you may need to base64 encode them or something. I'm not 100% sure since I have not worked with much outside of the english alphabet. Check out http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization for an XML Serialization tutorial. After reading that look up `XmlAttribute`, `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem`

Comment: Please try in google. Try this string path = "XML path"; DataSet ds = new DataSet(path);

Comment: Are you having trouble reading the file? Or trouble with character encoding?

Comment: Yes, as long as the file is stored in unicode format like UTF-8 (fairly standard) or UTF-16, UTF-32 it can be read in exactly the same manner as a file with just latin characters.

Comment: Add an XML header with UTF-8 encoding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007427/is-a-valid-xml-file-required-xml-header-declaration-xml-version-1-0-encodin

Comment: Just get your encoding right and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Linq To Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);//or XDocument.Load(filename);
var ships = xDoc.Descendants("Ship")
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    X = (string)s.Attribute("X"),
                    Y = (string)s.Attribute("Y"),
                    Orientation = (string)s.Attribute("Orientation"),
                    Length = (string)s.Attribute("Length"),
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: When I use XDocument.Load(filename);  - I have XmlException - Invalid character for the specified encoding.

Comment: @user1794316 you need to make sure that the file is saved as UTF-8.

Comment: @user1794316 you can load the xml by giving the correct encoding `var xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader("filename", Encoding.GetEncoding("xx-XX")));`

Answer (score 0):

use **xsd.exe** as already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml)

you can find it under

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\xsd.exe

or

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\xsd.exe

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me:

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(@"..\..\filename.xml", Encoding.UTF8));
        doc.Load(reader);

        var ships = doc.SelectNodes(@"//Ship");
```

Comment: Look what I have: <Ship X="3" Y="�" Length="3" Orientation="vertical" />