# XML file to Excel, error when opening

Tags: python, xml, excel

I have this file here:

```
<?xml?>
<table name="data">
<row et_kt="215846" et_nafn="" et_kt_maka="" et_kt_fjolsk="215846" et_kyn="X" et_hjusk_stada="1" et_faeddag="190201" et_danrdag="198612" />
<row et_kt="239287" et_nafn="" et_kt_maka="" et_kt_fjolsk="239287" et_kyn="X" et_hjusk_stada="4" et_faeddag="190401" et_danrdag="199106" />
.
.
.
</table>
```

Excel tell me the file is in a different format than the .xml implies. What's wrong with the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `<?xml?>` for `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

EDIT: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7007781/2517733) for some extra information about the issue.

Comment: Your edit: Thank you, that solved the problem! I was missing version="1.0".

Answer (score 1):

at first glance I'd say that that there is no valid xml declaration ie 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` 
or as it a microsoft product may be you should try `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>`