# Do CSS namespace attribute selectors work with XHTML/HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-selectors, xml-namespaces

I want to style elements with `xlink:href` attribute in a XHTML, however I can't make it work. My test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xyz="http://xyz.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>css namespace</title>
<style>
body { font-size: 20px; } /* Oops! A normal rule must not precede @namespace rules! */
@namespace html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
@namespace xlink "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
@namespace xyz "http://xyz.org";
html|p {
  color: blue;
}
[xlink|href], [xyz|href] {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
xyz|p, xyz {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- typos: 'xref' should be 'href', thank BoltClock's answer! -->
<p xlink:xref="aaa">&lt;p xlink:xref ...</p>
<p xyz:xref="aaa">&lt;p xyz:xref ...</p>
<!-- correctly styled elements: -->
<p xlink:href="aaa">&lt;p xlink:href ...</p>
<p xyz:href="aaa">&lt;p xyz:href ...</p>
<xyz:p xlink:href="aaa">&lt;xyz:p xlink:href ...</xyz:p>
<xyz:p xyz:href="aaa">&lt;xyz:p xyz:href ...</xyz:p>
<xyz xlink:href="aaa">&lt;xyz xlink:href ...</xyz>
<xyz xyz:href="aaa">&lt;xyz xyz:href ...</xyz>
</body>
</html>
```

When I test it in chrome 34 and firefox 30, I note that the `[xlink|href], [xyz|href]` rule isn't applied to XHTML's `<p>` elements, but is applied to `<xyz:p>` and `<xyz>` elements.

Why this happen? Don't namespaced CSS attribute selectors work with XHTML?

**Update:**

Yes, namespaced CSS attribute selectors work with XHTML, but not HTML. My code actually has 2 problems:

1. There are typos for attributes `xlink:xref` and `xyz:xref` (thank BoltClock's answer). I updated the code.
2. A normal CSS rule must not precede any @namespace rules, or the @namespace rules are invalid (my original post missed the `font-size` rule at the beginning). See [CSS Namespaces Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace/):

   > Any @namespace rules must follow all @charset and @import rules and precede all other non-ignored at-rules and style rules in a style sheet.

**Update 2:**
For HTML files, which doesn't support XML namespace, namespaced CSS selectors generally don't work with it. However, because qualified element/attribute names are treated as  simple names in HTML, these selectors work with HTML:

```
[xlink\:href]:hover, [xyz\:href]:hover { ... }
xyz\:p, xyz { ... }
```

Interestingly, namespaced selectors that targeting XHTML namespace still work with HTML files, like this:

```
@namespace html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
html|p { ... }
```

Another exception is foreign content such as SVG, suggested by @Alohci.

Comment: Are you serving the document as `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`?

Comment: I use .xhtml extension and test it locally, this should ensure application/xhtml+xml mime type.

Comment: If you want to use XML namespace you have to use a XML document. You current version looks like plain HTML. Set a XML header and use the correct content type to deliver that file.

Comment: I think the question title is back to front. XML/HTML elements do not support CSS at all, nor do they support CSS namespaces.

Comment: @feeela [XML declaration is optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007427/does-a-valid-xml-file-require-an-xml-declaration), and I did use content type `application/xhtml+xml`. Now it works as expected. Yes, the title should be reversed.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than just namespaced CSS attribute selectors don't work in HTML. Mostly they don't. In a few special cases they do. `xlink:href`, when it appears in foreign content such as SVG, is one such special case. For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/Kqr3M/

Comment: @Alohci Thanks! I think your comment deserves a separate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do. You've just set up either your markup or your CSS rules incorrectly.

Your attribute selectors are looking for elements with `href` attributes (in the respective namespaces), but your `<p>` elements have `xref` attributes, not `href` attributes, so they don't match.

Your `<xyz:p>` and `<xyz>` elements on the other hand all have `href` attributes, so those are the ones that end up matching your attribute selectors instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! The `xref`s are typos in the test code above, and my production code has another problem: style rules before @namespace rules. I updated my question to reflect this.