# How to use CSS attribute selector for an SVG element with namespaced attribute href?

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors

Why can't I select elements by their href-attribute?

**CSS**

```
/* Works */
svg image[type=overlay]{
    outline: 3px solid blue;
}

/* Doesn't work */
svg image[href*='temp']{
    outline: 5px solid red;
}

/* Doesn't work either */
svg image[href='wcs/WFL/position/temp2.png']{
    outline: 5px solid red;
}
```

**SVG**

```
<image display="inline" type="overlay" width="148" height="90" x="920" y="918" transform="" href="wcs/WFL/position/temp2.png"><title>B02003
Temp: 2</title></image>
```

I did notice the browsers turns the href attribute to `xlink:href` but `image[xlink:href*='temp']` doesn't work either.

How can I make this work?

**Edit:**
The SVG uses the following namespaces, I think this causes the problem but I don't know how to get around it.

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw5z4Lu8/1/)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/tw5z4Lu8/5/)

Firstly, in order to use `xlink` slectors, you need to to declare the `xlink` namespace at the top of your stylesheet [**according to the spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/#att-method):

```
@namespace xlink 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
```

Then, you can use the following attribute selector [**with a namespace prefix**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attrnmsp):

```
svg image[xlink|href*="temp"] {
    outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

> The attribute name in an attribute selector is given as a CSS
>   qualified name: a namespace prefix that has been previously declared
>   may be prepended to the attribute name separated by the namespace
>   separator "vertical bar" (|). In keeping with the Namespaces in the
>   XML recommendation

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the wildcard namespace on the attribute `[*|href]` (unless you have images with two different types of href attributes!).  More at [this answer about `.querySelector()`, for which declaring namespaces isn't an option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23047888/3128209).

Comment: Pleae note that this namespace declaration have to be placed at the top of your css file. More precisely, as stated in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628932/do-css-namespace-attribute-selectors-work-with-xhtml-html-elements, *a normal CSS rule must not precede any \@namespace rules, or the \@namespace rules are invalid*.

The CSS Namespaces Module Level 3 http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace/ says that > Any \@namespace rules must follow all \@charset and \@import rules and precede all other non-ignored at-rules and style rules in a style sheet.