# How to Persist Object as human readable XML File with XML Declaration?

Tags: c#, xml, persistence, human-readable

**Background**

I'm developing a desktop application that can create/open a *project* (think of visual studio). I need to persist such a project object to a XML file (think of .csproj) and load that project object from the XML file.

**Goals**

1. Store / load class MyProject to / from XML file
2. Human-readable XML (manual edits are bad, but it could simplify some tasks)
3. Valid XML that could be parsed from other languages / apps:

   - File starts with XML Declaration like `<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>` since user defined strings in any culture may end up here, thus the encoding is important. Also see [Does a valid XML file require an xml declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7007427/3311611)
   - Class namespaces can be specified (e.g. via `DataContractAttribute.NameSpace`)

**Q: What's the best way to persist an object into a readable & valid XML file?**

There are many ways to create XML and for me it seems the [DataContract] attribute is the way to go, since this allows for simple serialization and deserialization back into an object (goal 1). When using an XmlTextWriter I can also specify `Formatting.Indented`, which solves goal 2. However, I'm unable to create the XML declaration.

**Edit: Solution based on Accepted Answer**

Using the `XmlTextWriter` was a dead end, it does not accept `XmlWriterSettings`. There are too many (wrong/bad) ways to write XML. Using `XmlWriter.Create(..)` with the desired settings indeed produces human readable XML including declaration. The created instance is some internal class like `WellFormedXmlWriter`. The code:

```
    public static void Store<T>(string filename, T obj)
        where T : class
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
        {
            Indent = true, // human readable
            OmitXmlDeclaration = false, // don't omit the encoding
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };
        using (var xmlwriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings))
        {
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.WriteObject(xmlwriter, obj);
        }
    }

    public static T Load<T>(string filename)
        where T : class
    {
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filename))
        {
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)ser.ReadObject(xmlReader, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `XmlWriterSettings` instance to `XmlWriter.Create` in order to control serialization more finely. I believe [`XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you need.

[There's a small overview of XML output formatting on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbef2xz3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)