# How to remove headers from server response in java?

Tags: java

I have the following response in form of string and want to remove headers Content-Type and Content-Length from that string so that the resulting string has only xml data starting from < ?xml version ... upto < /Product>. How to do this in java.

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 107

<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Product>
<Id>11001</Id>
<Time>2012-06-09 14:18:22</Time>
</Product>
```

Comment: What have you _tried?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every xml document starts with the xml declaration `<?xml version...`, you may want to use .indexOf() and .substring() to get a string with only the xml document.

Assuming your String is called xmlString, it would probabily look like this:

```
xmlString = xmlString.substring(xmlString.indexOf("<?xml version"));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: “every xml document starts with the xml declaration…” No, they don’t.  [The spec even says it’s optional.](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-prolog)

Comment: The version is mandatory, while the declaration isn't. I should have been more precise. src: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007427/does-a-valid-xml-file-require-an-xml-declaration

Comment: Read those answers.  It’s optional in XML 1.0, which is what most of the world is currently using.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I must have missed it. I'll pay more attention next time :)