# There is an error in XML document (1, 1). When deserializing a simple xml string

Tags: c#, xml

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47296170/12960511) before but it didn't help me(it doesn't have an accepted answer either).

This test fails:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Xunit;

namespace ATest
{
    public class XmlSerializerTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void DeserializeTest()
        {
            string request = Serializer.ByteArrayToString(new RegisterRequest{ ... }
               .ToXml());

            RegisterRequest deserialized = request.DeserializeXmlString<RegisterRequest>();

            Assert.NotNull(deserialized);
        }
    }

    public static class Serializer
    {
        public static T DeserializeXmlString<T>(this string xmlObj)
        {
            T outputObject;
            using (StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xmlObj))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                outputObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader); // throws here
            }
            return outputObject;
        }

        public static byte[] ToXml<T>(this T obj)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            settings.Indent = false;

            using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);

            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, namespaces);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        // And convert that byte[] to string with this:
        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] bytes) =>
                Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }

    [XmlRoot(elementName: "RegisterRequest")]
    public class RegisterRequest
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public int WorkerId;

        [XmlElement]
        public string WorkerIP;

        [XmlElement]
        public int WorkerPort;
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (1, 1).'
>
> InnerException
> XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: And the result of you serialization looks like the string you have there hardcoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem here is `Encoding.UTF8` is UTF-8 encoding with BOM (byte order mark), which means `XmlSerializer` emits several bytes at the beginning to indicate said byte order mark. So result of your `ToXml` contains those non-character bytes at the beginning, and deserialization fails, because deserialization does not expect them. To fix, tell serializer to not emit BOM by doing this:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
//settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false); // false means no BOM here
```

By the way, text you pasted into the question does NOT contain said invisible characters, so with that specific hardcoded string you pasted the problem is not reproducable. However, since you included the code which produced problem string - one can reproduce it by manually calling `ByteArrayToString(ToXml(..))`.

Comment: _"with that specific hardcoded string you pasted the problem is not reproducable"_ as proven by https://dotnetfiddle.net/43pn98

Comment: @Fildor Sorry about that. I removed my reproducible thing from the question.

Comment: @H.Ebr No Problem. It was just meant as an addition to the answer.