# xmlstarlet doesn't work with xml version 1.1 files. Any alternative to use with Bash?

Tags: xml, jenkins, xmlstarlet

New Jenkins versions are using xml version 1.1 for [configuration files](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48463).
I used XMLStarlet to manipulate these files from a Bash script but XMLStarlet [doesn't support xml version 1.1](https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/discussion/226076/thread/bce7ab3d/)

Do you know of any alternative to XMLStarlet?

Comment: It seems a rather rash decision on the part of Jenkins. A great deal of XML software will never be upgraded to version 1.1, which was generally considered a lame duck.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you.

Answer (score 2):

Since I first posted this question I've found a couple of workarounds **valid only if you're not using a xml 1.1 specific feature** that is usually the case:

1st- `xmlstarlet 2>/dev/null`
xmlstarlet recognizes that xml 1.1 is unsupported and outputs a warning to STDERR (fd2) that you can see in the console. Redirecting (only) STDERR to dev/null makes the trick.

2nd- *removing the xml 1.1 first line declaration in the file*.
According to the xml standard if the declaration is missing, the file is considered to be xml 1.0. [Does a valid XML file require an XML declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007427/does-a-valid-xml-file-require-an-xml-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue before, in my case I had to install jenkins job config.xml and edit it and then upload it again to Jenkins.

As a workaround to fix this issue I used to replace the version from version='1.1' to version='1.0' and then apply XmlStarlet command and before upload the file I return the version to be version='1.1'