# For standalone SVG(.svg files), is it mandatory to include the the DOCTYPE and the XML declaration?

Tags: svg

For standalone SVG(.svg files), is it mandatory to include the the DOCTYPE and the XML declaration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A doctype is not required [some people recommend not using it](https://jwatt.org/svg/authoring/#doctype-declaration)

In XML 1.1 the XML declaration [is mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7007781/1038015) though. If it's omitted the document is supposed to be treated as XML 1.0 which may or may not be what you wanted. Note that browsers don't enforce this requirement so if that's your only use case you can omit the XML declaration.

Comment: Regarding the XML declaration: as of the time of typing this, Azure blob storage doesn't correctly detect the content-type of SVG files that lack this declaration; it thus stores them as `application/octet-stream` when it should store them as `image+svg/xml`.

Comment: Same with Google Storage.