# XML creation not formatting correctly

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I am using a similar xml creation code set up to the answer by @ssokolow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python). The code is running and the output is correct, however the format is different than a xml that is create by say [labelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg). I am not sure what is happening to cause this. The differences are:

1. There is no `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. Is this a big concern?
2. There is a blank space between `<filename>` and `<path>`
3. `<path>` looks as it is indented to `<filename>`. I do have it indented to `<annotation>`
4. Lastly, it seems that the labelImg xml indentations are "bigger". I don't think this is an issue, just something to note.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

csv_path = 'D:/path_to_csv/'
for csv_file in os.listdir(csv_path):
    df = pandas.read_csv(csv_path + csv_file)

    folder = 'images'
    filename = str('item' + df['tif_name'][0])
    path = 'S:/path/' + filename
    width = 1500
    height = 1500
    depth = 3

    root = ET.Element("annnotation")
    folder_elem = ET.SubElement(root, "folder").text = folder
    filename_elem = ET.SubElement(root, "filename").text = filename
    path_elem = ET.SubElement(root, "path").text = path
    source_elem = ET.SubElement(root, "source")
    database_elem = ET.SubElement(source_elem, "database").text = "Unknown"
    size_elem = ET.SubElement(root, "size")
    width_elem = ET.SubElement(size_elem, "width").text = str(width)
    height_elem = ET.SubElement(size_elem, "height").text = str(height)
    depth_elem = ET.SubElement(size_elem, "depth").text = str(depth)
    segmented_elem = ET.SubElement(root, "segmented").text = str(0)

    # Appending Function goes here

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write('C:output_path/item' + str(csv_file[:-4] + '.xml'))
```

**labelImg xml**
[image]

**My code xml**
[image]

Comment: If you are on Python 3.9, try the `indent()` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63373633/407651.

Comment: @mzjn unfortunately I am using python 3.7.

Comment: OK. Maybe you can use one of the other answers to "Pretty printing XML in Python" (there are more than 20).

Comment: using `write(..., xml_declaration=True)` you should get `<?xml ...>` but indentations are not important for computer/program to load data - they are important only for human. It may need to use `lxml` which has `tostring(..., pretty_print=True)`. OR `beutifulsoup` which has `soup.prettify()`

Comment: for small file you can even use `f-string` to genrate it. Create string with all xml tags and indentations and with elements like `{{width}}` to generate string with data - and save it as any text file using standard `open()`,`write()`, `close()`. And it

Comment: @mzjn if you have link to some question which describe how to do it then close it.

Comment: @furas is the `xml_declaration` even needed then? And yes, I have seen the `f-string` approach. Good to know about the indentations!

Comment: The XML declaration is recommended, but not mandatory. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7007427/407651

Comment: Cheers! appreciate the help. Welcome to close my question if you think it is necessary.

Comment: Oh how interesting. I made the `.xml` window full screen and the indentation "problem" went away.